# Is it possible to insert a break in the high charts legend?

Tags: highcharts

Over time i have gotten quite alot of elements in my HighCharts legend. I would like to sort them in a simple way, like insert a break to arrange the elements.

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.lineHeight it will help

Comment: Its not quite what i am looking for. I want to devide the elements in the legend into "categories" so it is displayed like this:

X X X X X<br />
Y Y Y Y Y<br />
Z Z Z Z Z<br />
Instead of: 

X X X X X Y Y Y Y Y Z Z Z Z Z

Answer (score 0):

Using `legend.width` should do the trick - [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.width) and [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/bw6rkrkg/)

Comment: Thanks for the input! But legend.width only affects the size of the legend box.

My goal is to insert breaks <br /> in the legend box, so i can sort the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing `itemWidth` and `itemMarginTop` should do the trick and divide legend items evenly.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemWidth
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemMarginTop

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/015fzv3a/

Comment: Is there a way to assign itemWidth and itemMarginTop to seperate legend items?