# split display legend in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have combination chart with highcharts, there are spline, pie and stacked. Is it possible to split legend or use vertical and horizontal layout together?

current layout legend is horizontal

*series 1 *series 2 *series 3 *series 4 *series 5 *series 6 *series 7 *series 8

I want the legend display to be

*series 1 *series 2 
*series 3 *series 4 *series 5 
*series 6 *series 7 *series 8

is it possible?

thanx

Comment: I don't think that's possible look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46662883/is-it-possible-to-insert-a-break-in-the-high-charts-legend/46665915#46665915)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done just by using Highcharts constructor options. You can achieve that kind of look and behavior by **wrapping some core functions**:

```
(function(H) {
  var merge = H.merge;

  H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype, 'getAllItems', function() {
    var allItems = [],
      chart = this.chart,
      options = this.options,
      legendID = options.legendID;

    H.each(chart.series, function(series) {
      if (series) {
        var seriesOptions = series.options;

        // use points or series for the legend item depending on legendType
        if (!isNaN(legendID) && (seriesOptions.legendID === legendID)) {
          allItems = allItems.concat(
            series.legendItems ||
            (seriesOptions.legendType === 'point' ?
              series.data :
              series)
          );
        }
      }
    });

    return allItems;
  });

  H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'render', function(p) {
    var chart = this,
      chartOptions = chart.options;

    chart.firstLegend = new H.Legend(chart, merge(chartOptions.legend, chartOptions.firstLegend, {
      legendID: 0
    }));

    chart.secondLegend = new H.Legend(chart, merge(chartOptions.legend, chartOptions.secondLegend, {
      legendID: 1
    }));

    p.call(this);
  });

  H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'redraw', function(p, r, a) {
    var chart = this;

    p.call(chart, r, a);

    chart.firstLegend.render();
    chart.secondLegend.render();
  });

  H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype, 'positionItem', function(p, item) {
    p.call(this, item);
  });
})(Highcharts);
```

**Highcharts options:**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    marginRight: 350 // create some space for the legend
  },

  legend: {
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    width: 300,
    align: 'right'
  },
  firstLegend: {
    y: -25
  },
  secondLegend: {
    y: 25
  },

  series: [{
    data: [5, 6, 7],
    legendID: 0,
  }, {
    data: [2, 3, 1],
    legendID: 0,
  },
  (...)
  {
    data: [1, 8, 2],
    legendID: 1
  }, {
    data: [3, 2],
    legendID: 1
  },
  (...)
  ]
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/r70fwasr/

This code can be optimized so that it works for more than 2 legends.

Answer (score 1):

You can use legend's itemWidth property. Here's the link

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    width: 500
},

title: {
    text: 'Legend <em>itemWidth</em> option'
},

legend: {
    itemWidth: 100
},

series: [{
    data: [6, 4, 2],
    name: 'First'
}, {
    data: [7, 3, 2],
    name: 'Second'
}, {
    data: [9, 4, 8],
    name: 'Third'
}, {
    data: [1, 2, 6],
    name: 'Fourth'
}, {
    data: [4, 6, 4],
    name: 'Fifth'
}, {
    data: [1, 2, 7],
    name: 'Sixth'
}, {
    data: [4, 2, 5],
    name: 'Seventh'
}, {
    data: [8, 3, 2],
    name: 'Eighth'
}, {
    data: [4, 5, 6],
    name: 'Ninth'
}]
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/legend/itemwidth-80/

Comment: how about if first and second in one row then break, third fourth fifth in the second row (below first and second), then break sixth seventh eight nineth in the third row (below sixth seventh eight). Is it possible?

Comment: hmm, I've done a quick search but couldn't find a code that can specify legend width for a specific series.

Comment: yup..that the reason I asked here, maybe someone knows about it, btw..thanx so much for your help