# Legend: break line so the following legends start from the next line

Tags: highcharts

I would like to separate legends with lines, for example I want to have 2 legends per line.

I tried to use **labelFormatter** but the **< br/ >** tag brakes the line only in the label's text not the line for legends.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
 ...
 legend: {
     enabled: true,
     useHTML: true,
     labelFormatter: function() {
       if (this.index == 2) {
         return this.name + '<br/>';
       } else {
         return this.name;
       }
     }
   },
...
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ivane_gkomarteli/t7ep0weq/

How can I change the **labelFormatter** so I have 2 legends per line?

**UPDATE**

Setting  **itemWidth** and **width** doesn't solve my problem because I want to break the line according to an 'if else condition'. For example:

```
     ...
     labelFormatter: function() {
       if (something == true){
         if (this.index == 2) {
           return this.name + '<br/>';
         } else {
           return this.name;
         }
       } else {
         if (this.index == 4) {
           return this.name + '<br/>';
         } else {
           return this.name;
         }
       }
     }
     ...
```

Possible output:

- 1st line: 2 legends
- 2nd line: 4 legends
- 3rd line: 4 legends

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46669398/3200799), you will find some ideas

Comment: @Core972 Setting the itemWidth doesn't solve my problem. I have updated my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've achieved layouts like this by setting the legend itemWidth and width:

```
  legend: {
    enabled: true,
        itemWidth: 200,
    width:400,
    align: 'center'
  },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t7ep0weq/1/

Comment: Thank you @Barbara, your answer is very helpful but doesn't solve my problem. I want to break line when a condition is true, so setting the width doesn't help. I will update my question. Thanks a a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts doesn't support that kind of layout manipulation on legend by default.

The solution here could be **extending the Highcharts core** so that it supports 2 legends or more.

Example for 2 legends:

```
(function(H) {
  var merge = H.merge;

  H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype, 'getAllItems', function() {
    var allItems = [],
      chart = this.chart,
      options = this.options,
      legendID = options.legendID;

    H.each(chart.series, function(series) {
      if (series) {
        var seriesOptions = series.options;

        // use points or series for the legend item depending on legendType
        if (!isNaN(legendID) && (seriesOptions.legendID === legendID)) {
          allItems = allItems.concat(
            series.legendItems ||
            (seriesOptions.legendType === 'point' ?
              series.data :
              series)
          );
        }
      }
    });

    return allItems;
  });

  H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'render', function(p) {
    var chart = this,
      chartOptions = chart.options;

    chart.topLegend = new H.Legend(chart, merge(chartOptions.legend, chartOptions.topLegend, {
      legendID: 0
    }));

    chart.bottomLegend = new H.Legend(chart, merge(chartOptions.legend, chartOptions.bottomLegend, {
      legendID: 1
    }));

    p.call(this);
  });

  H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'redraw', function(p, r, a) {
    var chart = this;

    p.call(chart, r, a);

    chart.leftLegend.render();
    chart.rightLegend.render();
  });

  H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype, 'positionItem', function(p, item) {
    p.call(this, item);
  });
})(Highcharts);
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6ob2qs1c/

Legends can be positioned via their `x` & `y` properties.  `chart.marginBottom` creates some space for the legends.